# Contents of receive buffer in serial application can't printf as a string -- why?

Tags: c, serial-port, arm, raspberry-pi4

I am writing an application to read serial data, one byte at a time, then parse this segment upon finding a '\n' character in this receive buffer. Everything seems to work until I attempt to `printf` the resulting character array (which I null-terminate after upon finding `\n` or the max of the char array.) I don't know why this is happening.

I have tried:

```
void check_uart(void)
{
    char ch;
    bytesRecv = read(serial_port, &ch, 1);                           // Reads character fine.
    printf("bytes received: %d\t content: %c\n",bytesRecv,ch);       // Still good here.
    if (bytesRecv)
    {
        if (ch != '\n')   // Check for newline from the host, still good here.
        {
            rbuf[rbuf_index] = ch;  // If NOT newline char, add char to buffer.
            if (rbuf_index++ < (sizeof(rbuf) - 1))  
                return;
        }

        // Process the command when user hits return OR the buffer is full.
        rbuf[rbuf_index] = '\0'; // Add null terminator to buffer, use as string

        printf("-----------------------\n"); // Prints the line
        printf("%s\n",rbuf);                 // **NOTHING**
        printf("-----------------------\n"); // Prints the line

        rbuf_index = 0;     // Reset rbuf's index now
}
```

and, a la the [Serial Programming Guide](https://www.cmrr.umn.edu/%7Estrupp/serial.html#4_2):

```
void check_uart(void)
{
    char ch; 
    bytesRecv = read(serial_port, &ch, 1);    // Reads character fine.
    printf("bytes received: %d\t content: %c\n",bytesRecv,ch);  // Still good here.
    if (bytesRecv)
    {
        bufptr += bytesRecv;
        if (ch != '\n')   // Check for newline from the host, still good here.
        {
            rbuf[rbuf_index] = ch; // If NOT newline char, add char to buffer.
            if (rbuf_index++ < (sizeof(rbuf) - 1))  
                return;                
        }

        // Process the command when user hits return OR the buffer is full.
        *bufptr='\0';
        printf("---------------------\n"); // Prints the line
        printf("%s\n",rbuf);               // **NOTHING**
        printf("---------------------\n"); // Prints the line 
        rbuf_index = 0;     // Reset rbuf's index now
}
```

General declarations and program structure, with these globals declared prior:

```
char rbuf[255];                 // Receive buffer
char tbuf[255];                 // Transmit buffer
char *bufptr;                   // Receive buffer pointer
uint8_t rbuf_index=0;           // Receive buffer index 
int serial_port;                // fd

int main(void) 
{
        serial_port = open(SERIAL_PRIMARY, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
        struct termios tty;
        memset(&tty, 0, sizeof(tty));
        while(TRUE) 
        {
                usleep(1000);
                memset(&rbuf, '\0' sizeof(rbuf));
                bufptr=rbuf;
                check_uart(); 
        }
        ...
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something very basic here. The program loops great, seems to run indefinitely and receives data successfully (accurately) from the host it reads. I just can't do anything with the data at this point. I know there is quite a lot to acquaint with when it comes to configuring a serial application, as outlined in the Serial Programming Guide, but my hunch is that it's more something in my character array syntax or overall approach there.

Thanks

Comment: one issue is that check_uart() reads only 1 character, and just before you call it, you clean out `rbuf` and reset `bufptr` back to the beginning of `rbuf`.

Comment: @mr. fixit Thanks for that. Another embarrassing signal that I should sleep more. The only character that would have made it to the print section, in this case, is the '\0' that replaced '\n' which would indeed show nothing.